# Narrow type of property in subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios

Today I came across a strange behavior that I did not expect Objective-C compiler would allow.

In UITableViewCell, there is a property named imageView of the type UIImageView. I subclassed UITableViewCell, and overwrote imageView, except I made it of the type AWImageView where AWImageView is a subclass of UIImageView. I thought it would not compile, but it does.  Everything works just fine.  I was very much shocked by the behavior.

Is narrowing the type of property in subclass allowed officially?  Or is this a bug in Objective-C compiler that made it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suspicion of being allowed to do this is well founded, but in this *particular* case you are OK...

In a strict subtyping interpretation of overriding, an overriding method may accept arguments of more general type and return a value of more specific type.

For example, using Objective-C, given:

```
@interface A : NSObject { ... }
@interface B : A { ... }
@interface C : B { ... }
```

and method M in B:

```
- (B *) M:(B *)arg { ... }
```

then in class C under strict subtyping this could be overridden in class C using:

```
- (C *) M:(A *)arg { ... }
```

This is safe because if you have a reference to an apparently B object:

```
B *bObj = ...;
```

and then method M called:

```
B *anotherBObj = [bObj M:[B new]];
```

then whether `bObj` is actually a B or a C the call is type correct - if it is a C object then the argument being a B is fine as it's also an A, and the result being a C is fine as it's also a B.

Which brings us to, *not quite*, your property; in Objective-C a property is just a shorthand for two methods:

```
@property B *myBvalue;
```

is shorthand for:

```
- (void) setMyBvalue:(B *)value;
- (B *) myBvalue;
```

If that property is declared in B and your override it in class C with a C-valued property:

```
@property C *myBvalue;
```

you get:

```
- (void) setMyBvalue:(C *)value;
- (C *) myBvalue;
```

and the method `setMyBvalue:` violates the strict subtyping rule - cast a C instance to a B instance and the typing rules say you can pass a B, the method expects a C, and chaos can ensue.

**However** in your case the property you are overriding is `readonly`, so there is no setter, and no danger.

Answer (score 1):

if AWImageView derives (subclasses) from UIImageView, it IS a UIImageView, so for the compiler all stays the same.

[from the docs:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-BAJCCBHC)

> [image]
>
> Figure 1-1 […] This is simply to say that an object of type Square isn’t only a square, it’s also a rectangle, a shape, a graphic, and an object of type NSObject.

Comment: Do you know of any documentation to back this up?  I am pretty sure Objective-C did not allow this earlier.  -(id)init returns id because it did not allow subclass to override a method and return a narrower type.

Comment: this is very normal behavior in any class based object orientated language, that supports inheritance. a subclass can be treated as the parent class. and u got it wrong with the init: it specifies id, so that any subclass can return an object of itself (or [see class cluster] another class, that will act similar).

Comment: Good quote from the docs, but just wanted to point out that the image in your quote is a dead link.