# Subclassed UIView, when set as default View In Storyboard, is not recognized by compiler without casting

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

In a simple "Single View" test project using XCode 4.3.3:

1. I subclassed UIView and specified it in the storyboard's Property Inspector as the class to be used as the viewController's default view.
2. In my custom UIView class, `TestUIView`, I define a property called "drawSwitch."
3. I import the header of my custom class in my viewController class.

When trying to compile the project, I was surprised that the compiler does not recognize my subclass with the line of code below, giving the error: *Property 'drawSwitch' not found on object of type 'UIView'*. This seems odd since my custom class `TestUIView` is indicated as the class for the viewController `view` outlet (shown in image below).

```
[self.view setDrawSwitch:2];
```

Yet if I cast it, the code compiles and runs fine:

```
[(TestUIView*) self.view setDrawSwitch:2];
```

When I view the properties of my viewController, my custom class is indicated as the Outlet for the view property.

So I am confused at what is going on with the storyboard here.

- Is storyboard/XCode letting me do something which the compiler isn't happy with, simply a GUI loophole?
- I know I can create an IBOutlet for my custom view (per below: "testView") but it seems redundant to create an additional outlet when the `view` outlet is already defined.

Am I missing something here? (beyond "that's the way it works", which may just be the case).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know anything about what you have set up in the storyboard. All it knows is that the `.view` property of your view controller will be a UIView. This works fine, since you can assign any subclass of UIView to this property at run time without a problem.

Your problem comes when you try to use the view property as if it were a more specific subclass. The compiler doesn't know that, at run time, what it thinks is a UIView will actually be a different class.

Your "redundant" outlet is actually the way that Apple has implemented this situation with UITableViewController. UITableViewController has a `.view` and a `.tableView` property, and these both point to exactly the same object - the table view.

An alternative is to override the property to have a different class, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770578/create-subclass-with-different-subclass-property) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711755/narrow-type-of-property-in-subclass) but this may have unforseen effects with a view controller. I'd recommend sticking with a separate property with a more specific class - it will certainly make your code more readable.

<sub>*Off-topic - this is my 1000th answer on Stack Overflow - you're welcome!*</sub>

Comment: Hey thanks for the concise answer (and congrats on the 1k!). Wasn't looking for hacks or to color outside the lines - just that it's confused me - the two outlets pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

There is something that you might not have posted but is wrong or may be I did not understand the problem right.

A simple example I tried works as expexted, no required cast and easy usage via the Storyboard.

So here is the code of SVTView.h:

```
@interface SVTView : UIView{

}
-(void)sampleSet:(int)value;


@end
```

and SVTView.m:

```
#import "SVTView.h"

@implementation SVTView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

-(void)sampleSet:(int)value{
  NSLog(@"setting value %d",value);
}


@end
```

And finally the usage within the ViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SVTView.h"

@interface SVTViewController : UIViewController{

  IBOutlet SVTView * testView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) SVTView * testView;

@end
```

And Viewcontroller.m:

```
#import "SVTViewController.h"

@interface SVTViewController ()

@end

@implementation SVTViewController

@synthesize testView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  [testView sampleSet:2];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

The referencing Outlet has been connected via Storyboard, so that the instance variable is used. The log console shows the disred result:

```
2012-07-28 07:51:02.227 SingleViewTest[1490:f803] setting value 2
```

Imo it is not redundant to use the correct class, the redundant part is probably the class cast.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is about setting the subclass as the class used by the default (built-in) `view` of the viewController. When I do this and have a `printf` statement in `initWithCoder`, it gets called - so my subclass is getting instanced as the default `view` without being defined as an IBOutlet. What is confusing is that the properties of this subclass are not being recognized by the compiler (without casting).

Comment: Ok, as far as i understand the IBOutlet is only for XCode and will be used for instrumentation code inserted by the GUI. And in deed it looks a bit confusing, however I would prefer to use the ordinary way to avoid some conflicts with future versions or updates of the Storyboard.

Comment: It is confusing - and I wondered why XCode/Storyboard would let me do it if it isn't supported. I'm not looking for hacks or anything, so I agree about following the supported methods.