# Objective-C inheritance and type casting

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance

I have a superclass O with a property UIView *view.

```
@interface O : NSObject
{
    UIView *view;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *view;

@end
```

UIView sublass:

```
@interface myView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIColor color;
```

I then have a sublass of O which has the following in its init:

```
view = [[myView alloc] init];
view.color = [UIColor redColor];
```

color is a property of myView used in some custom drawing code.

This causes the compiler to crash because UIView does not have a property color. I would be able to set the value using the setColor method, but it would be nice to be able to access the property via dot syntax.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Narrow type of property in subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711755/narrow-type-of-property-in-subclass)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770578/create-subclass-with-different-subclass-property and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248066/objective-c-narrow-instance-variable-types-in-subclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited:

in your specific case you need to declare `view` as `myView *view` instead of `UIView` in your .h file. then you will have access of custom color property.

Comment: I'm using the color variable in some custom drawing code in myView, it is not the backgroundColor.

Comment: you might be using setcolor for setting color of graphicscontext in `drawrect` but it is not available as a property for UIView

Comment: in your specific case you need to declare `view` as `myView *view` instead of UIView in your .h file. then you will have access of custom `color` property.

Comment: I know it isn't, I have subclassed UIView in myView, which has a color property. I will add an extra code sample to the question for clarification.

Comment: please read my recent comment - in your specific case you need to declare view as myView *view instead of UIView in your .h file. then you will have access of custom color property.

Comment: Thanks! So does that new declaration of *view override the property declaration in the superclass?

Comment: If you update your answer with that comment I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: I'm using the color variable in some custom drawing code in myView, it is not the backgroundColor.

Comment: are u declared property of color in myView class?

Comment: yep, outside of this class I can use it fine.

Comment: Have u declared MyView class extended from UIView?

Answer (score 0):

How would you be able to use `setColor:`? I don't see such a method for `UIView`. You can use `backgroundColor` property, and access it both with dot and method notation.

As for the dot vs. method notation, for all properties assigning to a `.propertyName` would be same as calling `setPropertyName:`. You wouldn't be able to call dot notation only if `setSomething` isn't a `@property`, just an explicitly declared method, but in Apple's framework I don't think it's possible.

Comment: setColor is a method in myView, so it would send the message anyway without having to know the type.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your `O` using `myView`:

O.h:

```
@class myView;

@interface O: NSObject {
    myView *view;
}
....
@end
```

O.m:

```
#import "myView.h"

....
```

In this case by declaring `@class myView` you don't need to import `myView.h` in `O.h` which is good. You just telling to compiler that there is a `myView` somewhere else. Now you could use your custom properties of `myView` instance.

The other thing if you're sure that `O.view` is always of type `myView` you could call setter like so:

```
[view setColor:theColor];
```

but I don't recommend this because if `view` will be an instance of some other `UIView` class you will get error, that there is no selector `setColor`.

I strongly recommend you to declare `view` property with proper class.